# Any solution for a DBMS App on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, database, sqlite

I have been trying to find an application to create a database (preferably sqlite) And I would like to create relational databases and query, however, I haven’t found any on the App Store to enable me to do so.
Does anyone know any way that I could manage a database on my phone?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) As it is currently stated, the scope of your question is pretty broad. If you can [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/335544/edit) the question and specify what exactly it is that you are trying to accomplish with the help of said tool, you'll stand a fair chance of getting quick and relevant answers.